# Nuclear physics

Tags: energy, nuclear

When considering Fusion,  the matter that gets converted into energy what specific matter is converted exactly like a quark and is most of the energy created from the matter  turning into energy?

Comment: Perhaps better a question on Physics SE - but, it all comes down to the relative binding energies of the parent and product nuclei...

Comment: Is it possible to convert some of the energy from fusion and convert it back to matter

Comment: Yes, of course. Particularly easy if you use fusion to generate an unstable nucleus.

Comment: yeah because I have this whole dream of making a business on transmutation

Comment: Good luck - you should learn about nuclear cross sections and how hard it will be to transmute elements in an economically viable way. Sure, nuclear powers made lots of plutonium, but it wasn't economically viable in particular.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a specific 'piece' of matter exchanged for energy in nuclear reactions. 
The mass difference comes from a more subtle change in the energy of the system: how stable the nuclei are compared to one another.
Mass and energy are a conjoined quantity (In fact, we often measure the masses of particles in energy units), so speaking of them as distinct entities is already questionable in this context. 
Famously, the relationship between the rest mass and energy is given by
$$
E = mc^2
$$
This relationship tells us that mass is energy and energy is mass, so something as simple as stretching a rubber band to store elastic potential energy will increase the mass of the rubber band. In fact, any kind of potential energy change will change the mass whether it's forming a chemical bond or walking up a hill. 
This is the principle at work in nuclear reactions. A helium nucleus has less mass than the sum of the masses of its component nucleons because they are more stable (i.e. lower energy) together than apart.

Comment: oh thank you thank you thank you thank you

Comment: so same for fission the protons neutrons and electrons mass dosn't change

Comment: you don't realize how much hope you have given me for my dream

Comment: You really  made my day thank you so much